# Like Dislike with single checkbox php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have checked all related questions on SO, but still looking for the best answer.

I am coding a review system where anyone can comment and logged in users can like their review (Like or undo their like only ...not dislike).

For that, I am using a checkbox and onClick call an ajax function that will like the review and if click again it will undo the action.

**problem**

Initially, When someone like the review, ajax call will like it and on Success it will change attr onClick to unlike(); function but again when i click on it it does not work fine...

**MY TRY**

```
<?php if($review['is_liked']){ ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="review_like" id="<?php echo $review['review_id'] . '-' . $review['customer_id'] . '-' . $review['product_id']; ?>" checked="checked" onclick="unlike(<?php echo $review['review_id'] . '-' . $review['customer_id'] . '-' . $review['product_id']; ?>);" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="review_like" id="<?php echo $review['review_id'] . '-' . $review['customer_id'] . '-' . $review['product_id']; ?>" onclick="like(<?php echo $review['review_id'] . '-' . $review['customer_id'] . '-' . $review['product_id']; ?>);" />
<?php } ?>
```

And JS (id passing to JS func looks like 1105-249532-18117)

```
<script>
function unlike(id){
    console.log('unlike');
    var id2 = toString(id).split('-');
    console.log('Unlike: '+id);
    console.log('split id: '+ id2);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/like_review',
        type: "get",
        data: {
            'is_liked': 1,
            'review_id': id[0],
            'customer_id': id[1],
            'product_id': id[2]
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            $('.btn-thumbs-up').find('input[type=checkbox][name=review_like]').attr("onclick","like(id);");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}

function like(id){
    console.log('like');
    console.log('Liked: '+id);
    var id2 = toString(id).split('-');
    console.log('split: '+id2);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/like_review',
        type: "get",
        data: {
            'is_liked': 0,
            'review_id': id[0],
            'customer_id': id[1],
            'product_id': id[2]
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            $('.btn-thumbs-up').find('input[type=checkbox][name=review_like]').attr("onclick","unlike(id);");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

the id i am passing to like/unlike function is not working fine in console and also split function even use toString func or wdout...

**Please fix this or suggest better way to do this task...**

Answer (score 0):

You could handle it at client side with simpler conditions. Change the <input> tag to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="review_like" data-id="<?php echo $review['review_id']; ?>" data-customer="<?php echo $review['customer_id'] ?>" data-product="<?php echo $review['product_id']; ?>" checked="<?php echo ( $review['is_liked'] ? "checked" : ""); ?>" />
```

And add this jQuery script to handle the checkbox change:

```
$('input[name="review_like"]').change ( function ()
{
  $.ajax (
  {
    url: 'index.php?route=product/product/like_review',
    type: "get",
    data:
    {
      'is_liked': $(this).prop('checked'),
      'review_id': $(this).data ( 'id'),
      'customer_id': $(this).data ( 'customer'),
      'product_id': $(this).data ( 'product')
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function ( json)
    {
      console.log ( ( $(this).prop('checked') ? 'Unliked' : 'Liked') + ' review ' + $(this).data ( 'id') + ', customer ' + $(this).data ( 'customer') + ', product ' + $(this).data ( 'product'));
    },
    error: function ( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
      alert ( thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```